# Webview app turns off after Splash Screen Android Studio

Tags: java, android, webview

I am creating a Webview application and I need to add Splash Screen at load time.
I tried different ways, with this it "starts", but after Splash Screen it just turns off. What can I do to make the application show Splash Screen and open correctly?

**SplashScreen.java:**

```
package com.example.evrika;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    },1000);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout             
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
  android:id="@+id/webView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.evrika;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webView.loadUrl("https://evrikaspace.ru/");


    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
        }
    };
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in logcat?

Comment: Probably this line is making noise `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by "it just turns off." ?

Comment: @isthemartin Yes, that was really the problem, thanks!

Comment: I'll put my comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

Probably this line is making noise `getSupportActionBar().hide();`